# How to transform text document to dictionary of keys and values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let us say I have a text document with lists of numbers in rows. How would I write a function that reads this document and returns a dictonary where the keys represent the row and the values of a key represent the numbers in a certain row, always starting with the smallest number while retaining the order of the others.

For example, reading the document:

```
3
4
1 8 7 6 4
5 2 3 6
```

should return a dictionary with values:

```
 {1: [3], 
  2: [4], 
  3: [1, 8, 7, 6, 4], 
  4: [2, 3, 6, 5]}
```

You see that with the fourth key, the n. 2 took the first place, since it is the smallest one when looking at the 4th row in the document, and so the order was reversed a bit, while it was left untouched for the 3rd, 2nd and 1st row.

I started with this already:

```
def to_dictionary(filename):
dict1 = {}
with open (filename) as file:
```

I am now lacking the knowledge to write up the code that will let me transform the document to the desired dictionary.

Comment: why are you using a dictionnary and not a simple array since you keys are just numbers?

Comment: This is so arbitrary in its requirements it seems to be homework. Am I right? You have a whole series of actions to do. Each of them is relatively simple. Take them one at a time, write some code to try and do that bit. If you can't get it to work ask a specific question about that bit following this guideline. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest starting with this part " the numbers in a certain row, always starting with the smallest number while retaining the order of the others." Write a function that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
def to_dictionary(filename):
   with open(filename) as f:
      first = {i:list(map(int, a.strip('\n').split())) for i, a in enumerate(f, start=1)} 
      return {a:b[b.index(min(b)):]+b[:b.index(min(b))] for a, b in first.items()}
```

Comment: Almost but this does not put the smallest number at the beginning of the values. For example, for the 4th key it returns [5, 2, 3, 6] when it should return [2, 3, 6, 5], the 2 being the smallest value.

Comment: @imagine_bodhi why smallest? why is 6 before 5?

Comment: Whatever number was before the smallest one gets moved to the last place so the entire row shifts until the smallest is first, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @imagine_bodhi ok

Comment: @imagine_bodhi please see my recent edit.

Comment: @Ajax1234 That should work but it is not very readable.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Next step is to read each line.

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

Then you have to split each line on the spaces. This gives you an `numbers` array.

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    numbers = line.split(' ')
    dict1[i + 1] = numbers
```

All together:

```
def to_dictionary(filename):
    dict1 = {}
    with open (filename) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            numbers = line.split(' ')
            dict1[i + 1] = numbers
    return dict1
```